# How to create an int that cannot be negative swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

This is a code 
I want do a game but money go under 0
If you can I want an alert for no enough money
I create an if money - cost > 0 and if self.money - self.cost > 0

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var money = 0
    @State var cost = 1
    @State var addToTap = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5.0){
            Text("money = \(money)")
            Text("$/tap=\(self.addToTap)")
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 50)
            Button(action: {
                self.money += self.addToTap
            }) {
                Text("  Tap!  ")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:20)
                        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 3))
            }
            Button(action: {
                if <#condition#> {
                    self.cost += 1;
                    self.money -= self.cost;
                    self.addToTap += 1
                } else {
                    <#statements#>
                }
            }) {
                Text("  Buy!  ")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:20)
                        .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 3))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Is there something wrong with your code? Where are you currently stuck?

Comment: State var money = 0
State var cost = 1                                                                                                        State var addToTap = 1                                                                                                                     Button(action: {
                if self.money - self.cost > 0 {
                    self.cost += 1;
                    self.money -= self.cost;
                    self.addToTap += 1
                } else {
                    
                }

Answer (score 0):

Use an unsigned integer (UInt) to create an integer that cannot be negative.

```
@State var money: UInt = 0
```

Comment: I think work but VStack do this errorStatic member 'center' cannot be used on instance of type 'HorizontalAlignment'

Comment: You sound like you are struggling to learn SwiftUI. I recommend deleting this question and going to [Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com). Hacking with Swift has a free 100 day SwiftUI course. The site also recently opened forums to ask SwiftUI questions.